# Facebook Insights - Gender & Age not available

Tags: facebook, facebook-insights

I have a question regarding *Facebook Insights*. When I go to the **Login** tab of our Facebook app, there is a section called **Demographics of New Facebook Logins**. Until recently, the data was available for both *Geography* and *Gender & Age* but since about a week ago, the *Gender & Age* tab has said *"No data is available for the current selection."* What is interesting is that the *Geography* data is still available.

We have experienced a slight drop in new Facebook logins but nothing too significant. Is there any option in the settings that we might have inadvertently changed that would cause such an issue? Or is there a minimum number of new logins that one needs to reach for this data to be available?

Any kind of advice or help is more than appreciated

Comment: I'd recommend you open a bug report on Facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/

Comment: A great idea, @Tobi, Facebook responded really quickly explaining that the described behaviour is by design. There is a certain minimum volume of new logins you need to get (unfortunately, they did not mention any specific numbers) for them to be able to consolidate a reliable demographic breakdown.